# Show checked items from dialog box into the previous activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkedtextview

I have a listview of shopping lists in a fragment and when I click one I get a new activity that shows a listview with all the products in the clicked shopping list. What I am trying to do is to add products this list by selecting some checkboxes in the newly created activity and pass them to the previous activity.

```
public class DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ShoppingList list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //defines the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_details);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_list_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        list = (ShoppingList) intent.getSerializableExtra("ShoppingList");

        ProductsOnListAdapter ad = new ProductsOnListAdapter(this, -1, Service.getService().getProductsOnList(list));
        listView.setAdapter(ad);

        FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(DisplayShoppingListDetailsActivity.this, ListOfProductsActivity.class));
                //This method here is not working...it says it cannot resolve the method
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear - are you saying that you want one activity to directly modify the contents of a prior activity?

Comment: yes, something like this. I want to click on the button in the dialog box and then I want to save all checked items and display them in the previous activity

Answer (score 0):

You really should not have one activity try to modify another activity's instance.  That will lead to bugs in your code.

Instead, in the first activity, you can use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to launch the second activity, then the second activity can use [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) to return data to the first activity.  This is all documented if you read the javadoc for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) under the heading "Starting Activities and Getting Results".

Comment: I have been reading about this but I cannot make it work for me...it drives me crazy. I really cannot figure it out. I will add the code in the post maybe you can see what I am doing wrong.